# How to reuse an std::thread as a member of a class

Tags: multithreading, c++11, condition-variable, stdthread

I have the following simple way of starting a thread with a call to a member function from within a lambda

```
auto worker_thread = std::thread { [this, &some_data] {
    this->SomeMethod(some_data);
}};
```

**Issue:**
I want to make `worker_thread` as a class member. Provided that `some_data` is also a member. I want to create it only once when the class constructor is called & destroy once when destructor called. At the same time I want to be able to pause and resume it at will. Looks like `std::condition_vaiable` might be handy in enforcing this technique ? Are there any ways other than using a `std::condition_vaiable`? Or any easier ways of doing this?

**Question:**
How can I design this to resume `worker_thread` on request & pause on request without having to create it every time want to execute `this->SomeMethod(some_data)`?

Comment: bad idea to make that thread a member variable. just use some threadpool implementation.

Comment: @DavidHaim Explain why it is a bad idea.

Comment: first of all, because different instances cannot share idle threads. also, if the worker threads are separated from a specific class design, the entire application can use these threads instead of creating specific set of threads for any specific use. regardless, if the OP implements this kind of mechanism by himself, he will eventually implement very primitive form of a threadpool already. also, in 99% cases I've seen, it's unlikely that "a thread" is a valid member of anything which isn't a "concurrentXXX object". usually, you want the services a thread may offer, not the thread itself.

Comment: interesting. so is it better to create a new std::thread every time than to put it as a member ?

Comment: no. it's better to use a threadpool.

Comment: a thread pool is a better option even in case of a thread which is private to a class & works only on a private member of that class ?

Comment: Re, "a thread which is private to a class."  Don't conflate threads with the _work_ that threads do.  When you said, "I want to be able to pause and resume it at will," it sounded as if you want the thread to perform a sequence of _tasks_.  If that is true, then there is no advantage in having the thread(s) that perform the tasks "belong to" your class.  The only thing that should matter is that the _tasks_ belong to your class.

Comment: A common pattern is to have an optional constructor argument through which the client of your class can pass in a reference to a thread pool.  Then, if the client elects _not_ to pass in a thread pool, your class can construct one of its own.